# AJAX loop not finishing first request before starting next

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a simple script that loops through all the inputs in a table, and submits an AJAX GET request for each one whose value is greater than one. For some reason, it seems that my script never manages to successfully complete all AJAX requests. I know if I set `async: false` on the AJAX request, it will succeed, but it is not best practice and also slows down the browser.

Any ideas how to fix this? I searched all over, found many relevant answers, but could not manage to achieve a fix for the script.

```
$('#OrderSubmit').click(function() {
    $('.OrderForm').find('.pid-input').each(function(j, element) {
        qty = $(element).val();
        if (qty > 0) {
            pid = $(element).data("pid");
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "/cart.php?action=add&product_id=" + pid + "&qty=" + qty 
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you preventing the form to be submited? BTW, why don't you send only one request to server handling all the product ids with relevant quantity?

Comment: Instead of sending X amount of AJAX requests, put the values of all `.pid-input` fields in to a single request and send that.

Comment: Because the server side script is closed source and out of my control...there is no alternative to doing single requests...

Comment: That is how asynchronous calls work... The Ajax call does not pause the loop. You either need to use promises or rethink how you are doing the looping.

Comment: The title of your question says you want to wait for one request to finish before starting the next. But then you say that your script doesn't successfully complete all the requests. How are these related? It seems to me that the requests do not complete because the browser is navigating to another page due to form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. 
May be you are sending request in a loop. From server side there might be restriction for subsequent request from one client. 

Its possible because one can crash the server or reduce the service quality by simply sending requests continuously.

Try giving  timeout of few milliseconds if this satisfies the server.

```
$('#OrderSubmit').click(function() {
var i=0;
$('.OrderForm').find('.pid-input').each(function(j, element) {
    qty = $(element).val();
    if (qty > 0) {

        i++;
        pid = $(element).data("pid");
        setTimeout(function(pid,qty)
          {
      $.ajax({ 
            url: "/cart.php?action=add&product_id=" + pid + "&qty=" + qty 
        });
          }.bind({},pid,qty),i*1000);

    }
});
});
```